# Oracle make column only editable by trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

We're at an impasse here trying to figure this out.

We have `triggerA` that updates `myColumn` from `tableB`, but we don't want our application users to be able to directly edit `myColumn`, only by calling `triggerA` which is on `tableA` (It is a "dynamic" column per say).

The problem here, is that if I simply added a trigger to `tableB` that prohibits changes to its `myColumn`, then `triggerA` won't be able to do its job either.

We can't make any changes at application level, and user privileges wouldn't solve either because they will need to be able to trigger `triggerA`.

I've searched for "passing parameter to triggers" here, but all the answers lie within the application level.

Is there any solution for our problem?

Comment: Thanks Mojimi.  Is it acceptable to you if, in the event a user tries to modify `myColumn` directly, they receive an exception (or at least that the database server throws an exception)?

Comment: @alexgibbs yes that would be acceptable, I will test your answer and report

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just login from the application to Oracle database as another user, not the schema owner, and properly configure privileges.

An Example Is Worth a Thousand Words - user `test`, schema `test`:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLEa(
   id int,
   myColumn int
);

CREATE TRIGGER update_table_B_mycolumn
AFTER UPDATE OF myColumn ON tableA
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   UPDATE tableB
   SET myColumn = :new.mycolumn
   WHERE id = :new.id;
END;
/

CREATE TABLE TableB(
   id int,
   myColumn int
);
```

---

Now grant appriopriate privileges to user `scott`:

```
GRANT ALL ON TableA to scott;
GRANT update (id) ON TableB to scott; -- update only ID, no myColumn
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON TableB to scott;
```

Note that UPDATE privilege is granted only for column `id` in tableA !
User `scott` has no update privilege on column `myColumn`

---

---

Now let login as `scott` and test our solution:

```
insert into test.tablea values(1,5);

insert into test.tableb values(1,5);

commit;
```

---

And now `scott` is trying to update `mycolumn` in `tableb`:

```
update  test.tableb set mycolumn = 3 where id = 1;

QL Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges
```

---

but `scott` is able to update `mycolumn` in `tablea`, and the trigger (fired with privileges of the schema owner - user `test`) updates a value of `tableb.mycolumn`:

```
update  test.tablea set mycolumn = 3 where id = 1;

select * from test.tableb;

        ID   MYCOLUMN
---------- ----------
         1          3
```

---

**EDIT - a solution based on triggers**

---

If you must use triggers, then keep a flag in a package that enables/disables the trigger.
Please look at the below example:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLEa(
   id int,
   myColumn int
);
CREATE TABLE TableB(
   id int,
   myColumn int
);
INSERT INTO tableA values(5,5);
INSERT INTO tableB values(5,5);
commit;
```

---

A package

```
CREATE or replace PACKAGE table_b_trigger_switch
IS
   PROCEDURE ENABLE_UPDATE_TRIGGER( sw BOOLEAN );
   FUNCTION IS_UPDATE_ENABLED RETURN BOOLEAN;
END;
/

CREATE or replace PACKAGE BODY table_b_trigger_switch
IS
   enable_flag BOOLEAN := FALSE;

   PROCEDURE ENABLE_UPDATE_TRIGGER( sw BOOLEAN )
   IS
   BEGIN
      enable_flag := sw;
   END;

   FUNCTION IS_UPDATE_ENABLED RETURN BOOLEAN
   IS
   BEGIN
      RETURN enable_flag;
   END;
END;
/
```

---

Triggers:

```
CREATE or replace TRIGGER prevent_update_tableB_mycolumn
BEFORE UPDATE OF myColumn ON tableB
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

   IF NOT table_b_trigger_switch.IS_UPDATE_ENABLED THEN
      raise_application_error( -20222, 'Updating of myColumn in TABLE_B is NOT ALLOWED' );
   END IF;
END;
/

CREATE or replace TRIGGER update_tableB_mycolumn
AFTER UPDATE OF mycolumn ON TableA FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  table_b_trigger_switch.ENABLE_UPDATE_TRIGGER( TRUE );

  UPDATE TABLEB b SET b.MYCOLUMN = :NEW.MYCOLUMN
    WHERE b.id = :NEW.id;

  table_b_trigger_switch.ENABLE_UPDATE_TRIGGER( FALSE );
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  table_b_trigger_switch.ENABLE_UPDATE_TRIGGER( FALSE );
  raise;
END;
/
```

---

A Test:

```
select * from tableb;

        ID   MYCOLUMN
---------- ----------
         5          5

UPDATE tableb SET myColumn = 3;
ORA-20222: Updating of myColumn in TABLE_B is NOT ALLOWED
ORA-06512: at "TEST.PREVENT_UPDATE_TABLEB_MYCOLUMN", line 4

UPDATE tablea SET myColumn = 3;
1 row updated.

select * from tableb;

        ID   MYCOLUMN
---------- ----------
         5          3
```

Comment: To make this a bit clearer I think it would be helpful if you added the schema name to the CREATE TABLE statements so it's clear they're in the TEST schema and not in SCOTT.

Comment: I understand that this would be an answer for some other people, but in my case it wouldn't work, a corporate application already manages the privileges, and we can't revoke privileges

Comment: @Mojimi I've updated my answer with a solution based on triggers.

Comment: @krokodilko thank you, I will make the tests and report

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to allow only the one `TRIGGER` to update `myColumn`, regardless of what user is attempting to make the `UPDATE`, you can do this with another `TRIGGER` that checks for `UPDATE`s to `myColumn` and rejects any that is not generated by the `TABLEA` -> `TABLEB` trigger.

Here is an 11g-compatible example. (From 12c onwards, `UTL_CALL_STACK` has some nice alternative tools).

First, create the test tables:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLEB(
  TABLE_B_KEY NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  TABLE_B_OTHER_DATA NUMBER,
  MYCOLUMN NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE TABLEA(
  TABLE_A_DATA NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  TABLE_B_FK NUMBER NOT NULL REFERENCES TABLEB(TABLE_B_KEY),
  MYCOLUMN_DRIVER NUMBER NOT NULL
);

Table TABLEB created.
Table TABLEA created.
```

Then, the `TABLEA` -> `TABLEB` `TRIGGER` that changes `myColumn`.  In this example case, it will just replace `myColumn` with the data in its own `MY_COLUMN_DRIVER`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TABLEA_MYCOL_UPDATER
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON TABLEA
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    UPDATE TABLEB SET MYCOLUMN = :NEW.MYCOLUMN_DRIVER
    WHERE TABLEB.TABLE_B_KEY = :NEW.TABLE_B_FK;
  END;
  /

Trigger TABLEA_MYCOL_UPDATER compiled
```

Then make the guard-`TRIGGER`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MYCOLUMN_DIRECT_GUARD
BEFORE UPDATE
  ON TABLEB
FOR EACH ROW
  DECLARE
    C_FORBIDDEN_MESSAGE             VARCHAR2(128) := 'Direct Modification of MYCOLUMN is forbidden.';
    C_ALLOWED_CALLER CONSTANT       VARCHAR2(128) := 'TABLEA_MYCOL_UPDATER';
  BEGIN
    IF ((:NEW.MYCOLUMN <> :OLD.MYCOLUMN) AND NOT (DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_CALL_STACK LIKEC '%TABLEA_MYCOL_UPDATER%'))
    THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20819, C_FORBIDDEN_MESSAGE);
    END IF;
  END;
/


Trigger MYCOLUMN_DIRECT_GUARD compiled
```

Then try it out. 
Initial Data:

```
INSERT INTO TABLEB VALUES(1,10,100);
INSERT INTO TABLEB VALUES(2,20,200);

1 row inserted.
1 row inserted.
```

Inital State:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEB ORDER BY 1;
TABLE_B_KEY  TABLE_B_OTHER_DATA  MYCOLUMN  
1            10                  100       
2            20                  200
```

Then use `TABLEA` to update `myColumn`

```
INSERT INTO TABLEA VALUES(1,1,1);
1 row inserted.

SELECT * FROM TABLEB ORDER BY 1;
TABLE_B_KEY  TABLE_B_OTHER_DATA  MYCOLUMN  
1            10                  1         
2            20                  200
```

Then, UPDATE other column in TABLEB:

```
UPDATE TABLEB SET TABLE_B_OTHER_DATA = 500 WHERE TABLE_B_KEY = 2;
1 row updated.

SELECT * FROM TABLEB ORDER BY 1;
TABLE_B_KEY  TABLE_B_OTHER_DATA  MYCOLUMN  
1            10                  1         
2            500                 200
```

And try to directly `UPDATE myColumn`:

```
UPDATE TABLEB SET MYCOLUMN = 7777 WHERE TABLE_B_KEY = 2;

Error starting at line : 1 in command -
UPDATE TABLEB SET MYCOLUMN = 7777 WHERE TABLE_B_KEY = 2
Error report -
ORA-20819: Direct Modification of MYCOLUMN is forbidden.
```

Comment: I believe that is precisely what I was looking for, a way to determine the caller

Comment: Thanks @Mojimi good to hear.  Is there arything else I can add that would help here, or does this answer your question?

Comment: Well I believe both answered with a solution, I will test and report the results

Comment: Thanks @Mojimi Sounds good.  If anything I can add just let me know.

Answer (score -1):

Oracle has introduced a new feature that allows you to create a "virtual column", an empty column that contains a function upon other table columns.
You cannot attempt to insert anything into the virtual column or you will get the new error:

ORA-54013: INSERT operation disallowed on virtual columns

Similarly for the update operation.

Using a virtual column also simplifies the use of derived columns. Transparently derived values do not require the application to calculate and insert an additional value. This also prevents the need to use a trigger on the table to provide an alternate implementation of this functionality. Using virtual columns in tables also eliminates the need to use views to display derived column values.